# Python Tkinter TTK Treeview Find Selected Items' ID Or Row

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I am creating a program which uses a TTK Treeview as an item hierarchy.
So far, the user is able to insert their own values into the tree, but I need to have a check running for when the user clicks on an item in the tree. I need the check to find the selected items ID and return it.

The check I have running relies on the `<<TreeviewSelect>>` bind. Currently, it finds the selected item and stores some information, but I need for it to also find the row the item is in or it's ID.

I tried implementing my own tag using a counter and the tag attribute of Treeview items, but it would return the number as a `NoneType`. I also tried using the value attribute, but it returned the same problem.

For information, I have read through many sites and a few questions on here, but none (that I have found) answer what I need.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you for taking the time to read.

Comment: Please read about and create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have already fixed my problem.

Comment: If you fixed your own problem, please submit your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can call the [selection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Treeview.selection) method to get a list of all selected items:

```
selected_items = self.tree.selection()
```

Comment: I am already using this, but I was having trouble passing an ID.
I have fixed everything now, though.